# Pass android listview to activity

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `Loader` class which just creates a `ProgressDialog` and show it.
Now, I have an `Activity` which I need to use the loader in it.
That activity loads items dynamically into a `ListView` member. I want to use the `Loader` class and show the `ProgressDialog` while loading the `ListView`.
I thought about loading the listview in a seperate class and send it to the activity, but I didn't find how to send "ListView" to another intent.
I've also considered making the `ListView` object a static object, so I would access it from another class, but I prefer not to (Static member is not recommended).
Any other ideas ?

```
package android.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class Loader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private ProgressDialog dialog;        

    public Loader(Activity activity) {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog.setMessage("Loading");
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) { 
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void res) {        
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what matters in a `ListView`is after all it's data. you can just send the data or set the already used data as `public static` and then reuse your `Adapter`.

I think this would be much easier and your code will be clean.